# Firefox retina support for background images (mediaqueries)

Tags: css, firefox, retina, pixel-ratio

I developped several websites using mediaqueries for making them retina ready.
On firefox I now see that all background images (managed by mediaqueries) are blurry, not retina ready.

Is this normal? Why firefox does not support the mediaqueries for pixel-ration yet?

Ex:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { ... }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox does support pixel ratio media queries with prefixes:

[-moz-device-pixel-ratio](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/CSS/Media_queries.html#-moz-device-pixel-ratio)